# How can I tell pvresize to expand a physical volume to include all available space?

Tags: lvm

We have a poorly implemented mysql server that had been built by a vendor. It has consumed 100% of available disk space, and as soon as any space is cleared out mysql grows to consume it. This is, obviously, a problem.

We currently have 2 disks in a raid 1+0, and just added 2 additional. We have added them directly to the RAID, so disk size should be essentially double what it was previously.

Pvresize would be our next step, but it only seems to facilitate growing to specific numbers (pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 20G /path/to/disk).

Is there an equivalent command that lets you specify to expand to all physical space on the disk (or in this case, the array)?

Comment: The --setphysicalvolumesize is used when you want to shrink a pv.  Omitting it entirely (`pvresize /path/to/disk`) should extend it.  If it doesn't, I'd suggest looking at dmesg and fdisk/parted to verify the space you added is actually there before continuing.

Answer (score 25):

As [yoonix](https://serverfault.com/users/143703/yoonix) pointed out in the [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/692340/how-can-i-tell-pvresize-to-expand-a-physical-volume-to-include-all-available-spa/692428#comment853673_692340), the pvresize without options resizes **physical volume** to the size the operating system reports for the underlying partition.

```
pvresize /dev/sdXY
```

`--setphysicalvolumesize` option can be used to shrink the **physical volume** or to override the operating system autodetected size (if for some reason is wrong).

To extend a **logical volume** to full available capacity you have to pass to `lvextend` explicit option:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/VGNAME/LVNAME
```

Comment: I used this command on my centos box with 2 partitions: sudo lvextend -v -r -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root. -v will give a great verbose output.

Comment: The answer was very helpful :D